# EvaluateScriptAsync hangs the browser in CLR CefSharp application

Tags: visual-c++, clr, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am implementing an MFC MDI view class in which I am using Cefsharp winforms as CLR class.I am facing an issue about using EvaluateScriptAsync in Cefsharp. I want to run a javascript code with EvaluateScriptAsync and then return the result to my native view class(CWinFormsView).
The ExecuteScriptAsync works well.
Also my View app loads COM components whenever app class is created.
The problem is that the browser freezes when I use wait in EvaluateScriptAsync,it never returns and shows a message box saying the "Server might be busy" with buttons "Switch to", "Retry" and "Cancel".

Below is my implementation for Browserctrl CLR class:

```
System::String^ CEFBrowser::CLR_UserControl::Eval(String^ sScript)
{
    auto task_js = CefSharp::WebBrowserExtensions::EvaluateScriptAsync(m_Browser,sScript);
    task_js->Wait();
    if(task_js->IsCompleted)
    {
        return task_js->Result->ToString();
    }
}

The task_js->Wait() never returns.
```

PS- I am using CefSharp.WinForms.84.4.10 and cef.redist.x86.84.4.1 nuget packages.

Comment: EvaluateScriptAsync is an async function and your calling it in a sync fashion, this is not recommend. Your probably blocking a thread you shouldn't,  not enough code to be sure. Make sure your not creating your COM on any of the CEF threads, you'll have nothing but problems.

Comment: Thankyou for the insight....but how can I get the result from a javascript?All I could find was EvaluateScriptAsync used with await on online blogs.

Comment: ContinueWith might be an option.